# Screen size issue with 7 inch

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have lenovo tablet with 7 inch screen with 1480*800 screen and 216 dpi

I don't know if this work with layout-sw600dp or layout-hdpi

which one i should to use ?

Comment: Try creating two different layouts -- one in each folder -- and see which one it picks. That should get you what you need!

Comment: Ok this i will do thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct one is

```
layout-sw800dp
```